# Is it possible to include a link in a translation?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, localisation

We disabled the guest checkout. To try to make the response a bit more user friendly, I tried to do this in our translation file in our theme:

```
"Guest checkout is disabled.", "You must <a href=""/customer/account/login"" alt=""Customer Login"">login</a> or <a href=""/customer/account/create"" alt=""Create an Account"">create an account</a> to checkout."
```

The result, however, is that it is escaped and just prints out as text on the screen.

[image: Picture of the output on the Cart screen]

Can we achieve this through translation? My feeling is likely that this is a security protection. If that's the case, is there another way to do this simply? For now, I've just removed the links. The text is far better than "Guest checkout is disabled." even without the links, but the links would be a better experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you've done unfortunately.

It's going to be a bit of trial and error but if you want translations with variables you have to change your template logic and then edit your translations a bit differently assuming you are translating to something other than english.

```
<?= __("You must"); ?>
<a href="<?= $block->getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>" 
   alt="<?= __("Customer Login"); ?>"><?= __("login"); ?></a> 
   or 
<a href="<?= $block->getUrl('customer/account/create'); ?>" 
   alt="<?= __("Create an Account"); ?>"><?= __("create an account"); ?></a> <?= __("to checkout."); ?>
```

And individually translate strings

"You must","Vous devez"

etc

That's generally how Magento team does it

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

Lots of small snippets of text.